# A box contains 5 blue balls, 4 red balls and 9 green balls. A person takes out 3 balls from the box.

Tags: probability

I'm trying to remember the intuition behind probability theory because it has been like three years since i studied it for the last time. I'm trying to solve the next problem:
A box contains 5 blue balls, 4 red balls and 9 green balls. A person takes out 3 balls from the box.

- Find the probability to obtain 3 green balls.
- Find the probability to get 3 balls with the same color.
- Find the probability to get 3 balls with different colors.

My attempt is this:

- $P(A)=\frac{9\choose3}{18\choose3}=\frac{84}{816}$
- $P(A)=\frac{{5\choose3}+{ 4\choose3}+{ 9\choose3}}{18\choose3}=\frac{10+4+84}{816}=\frac{98}{816}$
- $P(A)=\frac{{5\choose1}{4\choose1}{9\choose1}}{18\choose3}=\frac{5\cdot4\cdot9}{816}=\frac{180}{816}$

I'm not sure of what i'm doing, so i would like to know if i'm doing well. Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Assuming the balls are not being put back after each selection, this is all correct.